# 12.04: Persistent Gimp 2.2 from Gimphoto or Gimpshop. Cannot install 2.8

Tags: gimp

I have a very messed up installation of Gimp.

Some time ago I installed Gimpshop or Gimphoto (can't really remember which) and it installed Gimp 2.2. Didn't work for me and tried to remove it.

I've followed all Gimp remove, autoremove, clean, update and upgrade instructions I've found here to no avail. Now Software Center doesn't even show 2.8 but instead it does 2.6.

I've installed and removed Gimp from terminal nth times. Running Gimp from the dash doesn't do anything but entering "Gimp" in the terminal prompt gives me a 2.2 installation screen.

[image: Gimp 2.2 install screen]

Cannot for the life of me find and remove the darn leftover garbage.

How can I completely clean my system (12.04, fully updated today) from everything Gimp so I can give 2.8 a try?

Anticipated apologies if this is a dupe but I've run through all messages with a Gimp tag and none has helped me.

sudo apt-get install -f gives me 0,0,0,0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 does not come with Gimp 2.8, it still includes Gimp 2.6.

If you want to try 2.8, you can either wait until Ubuntu 12.10 comes out, or to add a PPA for Gimp 2.8. Here are [the instructions how to install Gimp 2.8 on WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/gimp-28-stable-finally-available-for.html).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Before doing this you might run `find / -name gimp` to find and possibly remove all files with that name - I suspect that you just have a file with this name in your home directory or something like that, that's why entering `gimp` interminal starts some installer.

Comment: Sergey, many thanks! The find / -name gimp command in a terminal revealed a lot of 2.0 and 2.2 garbage. I had to go "su" in order to delete them but it's done now.

Comment: What I cannot get to work is the install of 2.8; the terminal still installs 2.6.

Comment: @JorgeM.Treviño I had the same problem with you. Go to `Update Manager`, click `Settings`, `Other Software` tab and make sure that the `otto-kesselgulasch/gimp` entries are selected!

Answer (score 1):

Use this if gimp is already installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```